# Get the Login and Register Form side by side in Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, account

Hi I'm using WooCommerce for my Wordpress website. The My-Account Page shows a Login and Register Form, if you are not logged in.

For some reason the register form is under the login form.

I tried this CSS:

```
.woocommerce-account .col-1, .woocommerce-account .col-2 {
width: 10%; float: left !important;}
```

Does someone know how to get it side by side?

Comment: we need to at least see the html structure

Comment: Voting to close because the question does not contain a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** You should try the following:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col2-set#customer_login .col-1,
    .col2-set#customer_login .col-2 {
        float: left !important;
        width: 47% !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important; /* optional */
        border:none !important; /* optional */
    }
    .col2-set#customer_login .col-1 {
        margin-right: 6% !important;
    }
    .col2-set#customer_login {
        width: 100% !important;;
        float: none !important;;
    }
}
```

Then you should try to remove:

- `!important` one by one to see if they are really necessary
- `margin-left: 0 !important;`
- `border:none !important;`

This should works